# Подскажите с помощью каких виджетов можно реализовать это

Tags: android, android-widgets

С помощью чего реализованы эти области внизу?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это просто панель в дополнительном слое (FrameLayout) - любой контейнер, с помощью которого удобно скомпоновать нужную разметку. В последнее время есть инструмент из SDK - [BottomSheetDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog.html). Вот [Пример](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-bottom-sheets-example-using-appcompat-v23-2-support-library/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Легко узнать какие виджеты используются, имея исходный код, можно при помощи **Layout Inspector'a** в Android Studio. Вызвать его можно перейдя во вкладку **tools** на панели задач студии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При вызове инспектора на экране устройства/эмулятора должна находиться та сцена, которую вы хотите инспектировать.

**UPD:**

Ок, раз необходимо всё готовенькое, использовались эти компоненты:

- `SeekBar` (полоса прогресса)
- `TextView` (процентное значение прогресса)
- `View` с высотой `1 - 2dp` (горизонтальная линия)
- Возможно `FloatingActionButton` / кастомные круглые кнопки
- `Button` со стилем `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"` (кнопка "сбросить прогресс")

**UPD2:**

Варианты размещения элементов внизу экрана:

- `CoordinatorView` как родительский `ViewGroup` для этой панели + `BotomSheetBehavior`
- `RelativeLayout` как родительский `ViewGroup` для этой панели + `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` в свойствах `xml` у панели
- `FrameLayout` как родительский `ViewGroup` для этой панели + `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` в свойствах `xml` у панели

Comment: Бесполезный ответ. Имея исходники ясное дело, что я смогу узнать.

Comment: @Ник обновил ответ

Comment: наверное основная проблема в том. чтобы вывести эти стандартные комоненты поверх текущего экрана в маленьком окошке снизу?

Comment: @pavlofff если проблема действительно в этом, то вы дали исчерпывающий ответ, я лишь перечислил `view` внутри компонента с `BotomSheetBehavior`

Comment: Я всего лишь написал комметнарий, который может дать верное направление для решения вопроса, потому что полоценный ответ мне писать некогда. Ответ написали вы и будет замечательно, если он как можно полнее решит проблему в вопросе. Если вас смущает, что вы воспользуетесь моим советом, то не стоит - если бы я хотел, то сам бы написал ответ, а не комментарий, но позже.